# the bodhi of kunti

Tags: mahabharata, philosophy, kurukshetra

A boon - to beget a child with any god of her choice - was given to Kunti by Durvasa the sage he knowing she was unavailable to give natural childbirth.  henceforth she wanted to test the quality of her gift and summoned the sun god Surya.  Having realized she was unwed she cast the boon baby down the river.  was kunti not mindful of her situation?

Comment: @ blue-ego, wt.? I have just added kunti n karna in ur tags why r u crying man.?

Comment: @Savdy I want my original wording man? So I can become a better machine...

Comment: @blue-ego. So, u want ur original wording to Better machine huh.? Ok tathastu. ✋✋✋.. Lol... I have changed it to what it was previously. Now, Enjoy..

Comment: @blue_ego It's clear within the Mahābhārata, that she did it in order to save herself from stigma and dishonor. An unmarried women, and that too a princess having a child is not something that would be viewed in a good light by many, people would talk about it, her reputation would disappear. She feared how public would react to it. So, it was a mix of both irresponsibility towards her deed and fear that made her take such a step. She did regret that later.
Is she really at fault? Well, she is at fault towards her child, but her point of view is understandable if you look from her shoes.

Comment: Is Kunti to blame? I think it's more the society to blame which was so misogynistic. If the society wasn't like that, why wouldn't she have considered accepting the child? She wasn't heartless that she would kill her own child.  It's the society which made her take that decision. Of course, she was also not willing to take the responsibility, but that is another case. So, I don't blame Kunti for what she did.

Comment: Even for an unmarried woman now, it's troublesome matter. Although, society is a lot better and accepting than Mahābhārata since there are many single unmarried mothers now. But still, every unmarried girl would be in a dilemma of what to do if she is pregnant not by her choice, of how she will face the society and her family. Is the woman really to blame? It's not as she was willing to have a child. If she willingly had the child, then of course it's her responsibility.

Comment: @Bingming good point..the man is always to blame...

Comment: Yup, today's scenerio, a man is always guilty till proven innocent. Just like Johny Depp/Amber Heard's defamation case. Prd..